# How to find string count using SQL query of a particular id in a column?

Tags: mysql, sql

For Example

If i have a table name called `Vegans` and column Name called `Fruits`:-

```
ID     Fruits 
1      Orange,Apple
2      Orange,Apple
3      Apple
4      Orange
```

How to get count string count of a particular `'ID'` in the column name `Fruits` ?

Comment: Fix your data layout to have a junction table (one row per id and per fruit.  Then use a simple aggregation/where/join to do what you want.

Comment: Which database you are using

Comment: I do recommend to fix your table as Gordon Linoff suggested. To be able to count fruits in a `Fruits` field, you have to split data on comma. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17942508/sql-split-values-to-multiple-rows

Comment: @Indian : im using mysqlDB for learning !

Comment: Do you want to know how many fruits are there for a id (like id1 = 2, Id2 =2, ID3=1...) or how many IDs are there for a fruit (like orange=3, apple=3)?

Comment: @KI78 Yes,Exactly that's wat i am expecting ( ID1=2,ID2=2,ID3=1,ID4=1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple way to achieve this is by taking the count of commas that splits the fruits, and add one (in case there is only one fruit)

```
SELECT ID,char_length(Fruits) - char_length(REPLACE((Fruits), ',', ''))+1 AS FruitCount
    FROM Vegans
    WHERE char_length(Fruits) > 0 AND ID = 1
```

As many people suggests you should have each entry of fruit in a separate row, with a link field in addition to the ID field. For example like this:

```
ID, VeganPersonID, Fruit
1, 5, apple
2, 5, peaches
3, 1, apple
```